# Apache2 crash after SSL install

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to install ssl on my apache2 ubuntu 14.04. After I install all my credentials and restart my apache I get

> caught SIGTERM shutdown

There is no more error or explanation.
I created a folder in etc/apache2 called ssl and generated my csr & key there using this command:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout yourdomain.key -out yourdomain.csr
```

Here is my 000-default.conf in sites-available:

my 000-default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomain.com/
Redirect / h t t p s ://mydomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName mydomain.com:443
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/962dfc9e10c76031.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mydomain.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile  /etc/apache2/ssl/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 <Directory /var/www/html/>
     AllowOverride All
     order allow,deny
     allow from all
   </Directory

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Then I call

```
a2enmod ssl
```

and restart apache. But I get SIGTERM shutdown. I'm so confused

Note: I also have cloudflare ssl mode on strict

Comment: Do you see any specific entries in ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log? Also remove the forward slash from the following entry: ServerName mydomain.com/

Comment: @StackOverFlowUser I use this command sudo tail -100 /var/log/apache2/error.log. I can just see the SIGTERM shutdown the rest is normal

Comment: Your question seems to be best suited for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: `h t t p s ://mydomain.com/` - Are these whitespaces in the URL present in your config file as well? If yes, they shouldn't be.

Comment: @jweyrich stackoverflow doesnt allow to type in a url with https so added space

Comment: @jweyrich I'll ask it there too thanks

Comment: @HiradRoshandel: Ah, okay! Let us try to migrate it there first.

Comment: @jweyrich http://serverfault.com/questions/718660/server-crash-after-ssl-install